# why fscanf returns a D from a file with context?

Tags: c, file

This section of my C code is designed to read from a file.

```
int Id;
char schoolname[10];
char DOB[20];
char gender[300];
char EVENT[20];
char FNAME[20];
char LNAME[20];
if(strcmp(GENDER,"MALE")==0){
   FILE *PTR = fopen("./REGISTER/INDIVIUALL_ALL_AROUND_MALE_EVENT.txt", "r+");
   if (PTR == NULL) {
      printf("Error File 1 Not Created");
   } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < UNTIL; i++) {
          fscanf(PTR, "%d%s%s%s%s%s%s", &Id, &schoolname[0], &DOB[0],
                           &gender[0] ,&EVENT[0],&FNAME[0],&LNAME[0]);
          printf("\n%d\t%s\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%s", Id, schoolname, DOB,
                           gender, EVENT, FNAME, LNAME);
       }
       fclose(PTR);
    }
```

[this is the context of my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgCn5.png)
My issue is that the when printing gender it returns a D.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzLwl.png)

I have tried, changing the size of each array and even the format in which I scan.

Comment: Please don't include images of the text in the file — include the text in the question (treat it as code, or use `none` after the triple-backtick, or use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` as a comment with blank lines on either side).

Comment: `char gender[300];`? That's politic!

Comment: @user3121023 that could be the issue. It would be funny if the string was overflowing and writing into the memory space occupied by gender.

Comment: @user3121023 Post it as an answer

Comment: Thank you -user:3121023, its my fist time posting thanks for advice.